# Remove substring from entire Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with three columns and every string in these columns ends with '\n'

Example:

```
test\n | abc\n | 123\n
```

Now, I want to get rid of these '\n' and achieve:

```
test | abc | 123
```

I only find solutions where substrings are removed from certain columns, but I want to remove this substring from the entire DataFrame

I would therefore be very happy if someone had a solution to my problem.

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df = df.apply(lambda s: s.str.strip())
```

To limit to a list of columns:

```
# cols = ['col1', 'col2']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda s: s.str.strip())
```

Comment: Thank you, your approach worked very well! Since I also got some "\n" inside some strings I slightly modified your solution 

from: df = df.apply(lambda s: s.str.strip()) 
to:  df = df.apply(lambda s: s.str.replace("\n",""))

Comment: @RKF yes sure, I thought this was only for the final '\n' ;)

Comment: Is it needed to use `index = True` or something like that? It's not working for me.